# Animate a card flipping from front to back

Tags: java, android-studio, jquery-animate, fade, flip

I'm trying to provide a simple solution that would give the effect of a card flipping over. I have the code for changing between bitmaps when the card is clicked, I just need an animation effect.
I've tried fading in and out and also shrinking/expanding the card but all of the tutorials I could find required the use of plugins and xml files.

Here is the code for the changing between card front and back bitmaps from the java class for the card:

```
public void flip(){
Bitmap front = mGameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager().getBitmap("card01");
Bitmap back = mGameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager().getBitmap("card01-back");
    if(this.getBitmap().equals(front)){
        this.setBitmap(back);
    }else{
        this.setBitmap(front);
    }
}
```

The flip is then called in this excerpt of code that is from the java class for the gamescreen in which the card is displayed:

```
}else if(currentEvent.type == 5){
                    Card card = getCardIfTouched(currentEvent);
                    if(card != null){

                        card.flip();
                    }
                }
```

Looking forward to seeing replies to this and hopefully there is a simple solution to giving the effect of the card being flipped.

Comment: I imagine you'd need a .gif for something like this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036153/62576 - Click the *Run Snippet* button and then move your mouse over the rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that solution is for a different problem. I need to fade the first bitmap out and fade the second one in. They already transition between each other on click, what I need is the appearance that they are fading between each other.